# Bash subcommands with arguments

Tags: bash, arguments, command

I have a script in bash as such:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

if [[ "$#" == 0 ]]; then
    printhelp
    exit 1
fi

# process options
while [[ "$1" != "" ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    -n | --name)
        shift
        _NAME="$1"
        ;;
    -i | --id)
        shift
        _ID="$1"
        ;;
    -h | --help)
        printhelp
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        printhelp
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

This works fine, but I want to add some "actions" that will take the above params. Eg. usage will be:

```
./run.sh create --name foo --id 1234
./run.sh delete --id 1234
```

I am not able to figure out the right syntax, and I am unable to phrase this requirement into appropriate words to be able to search.

Comment: List all the possible parameter formats.  Then write code to understand that.  Ex. if you always have an action parameter (create or delete in your example), store that action in a variable, call `shift` and the rest of the arguments are ok to be processed with your existing code.  You could look into `getopts` as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sub-command you can handle it this way:

```bash
function main(){
    if (( ${#} == 0 )); then
        main_help 0;
    fi

    case ${1} in
        help | version | encrypt | decrypt )
            $1 "${@:2}";
        ;;
        * )
            echo "unknown command: $1";
            main_help 1;
            exit 1;
        ;;
    esac
}

main "$@";
```

Then wrap each sub-command is a function. And inside each function you will have isolated options and parsing it separately.

For example:

```bash
function decrypt(){
    if [[ ${#} == 0 ]]; then
        decrypt_help;
    fi

    local __filename='';
    local __salt='';
    local __anchor=false;
    local error_message='';

    while [ ${#} -gt 0 ]; do
        error_message="Error: a value is needed for '$1'";
        case $1 in
            -f | --file )
                __filename=${2:?$error_message}
                shift 2;
            ;;
            -s | --salt )
                __salt=${2:?$error_message}
                shift 2;
            ;;
            -a | --anchor )
                __anchor=${2:?$error_message}
                shift 2;
            ;;
            * )
                echo "unknown option $1";
                break;
            ;;
        esac
    done

    echo filename: ${__filename:-empty};
    echo salt: ${__salt:-empty};
    echo anchor: $__anchor;

    exit 0;
}
```

Here is a full version [bash-CLI-template](https://github.com/shakibamoshiri/bash-CLI-template/blob/master/subcommand.sh) I have used in my projects

demo ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
create() {
     # actiony stuff here
}
ACTION=$1 ; shift
# put all your argument parsing here
$ACTION   # call
```

However, since different actions probably have different arguments, I'd probably do it differently...

```
create() {
    # argument parsing for create
    # then do your create stuff
}
ACTION=$1 ; shift
$ACTION "$@"
```

This will pass all your arguments to your subfunction, which can then parse its own arguments.